# How can i save the scroll position in a recycler view after every time i recreate it?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

below is the method which is called every time a button is clicked and it creates a list with new data

```
public void fire(View v) {
    String temp = editText.getText().toString();

    myRecyclerView = new MyRecyclerView(this, 500, temp);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    myRecyclerView.setClickListener(this);
}
```

how can I save the scroll position so that when next time the button is clicked, list remains on the same position

Comment: Why r u create a new View every Time ? Whats the use case here ?

Comment: im making an app where user will enter any text and it will be converted into different fonts, thats why i have to recreate whole list again

Comment: For this you do not have to create a new view each time . Changing the data set should be enough.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, use this every time you re-create it.

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);
```

Code:

```
public void fire(View v) {
    String temp = editText.getText().toString();

    myRecyclerView = new MyRecyclerView(this, 500, temp);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myRecyclerView.setClickListener(this);
    //assuming th layout is loaded. set pos as the position you want to scroll to
    int pos=0;
    linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0); 

}
```

Comment: thank you, i got what ur saying but can u also tell me how would i get the pos value each time the button clicked, i tried declaring a method in adapter class and i tried to call getAdapterPosition() in it but i think i can not use this method there, Do you have any idea please

Comment: you can use the recycle view adapter to get the position when it's being created.

Comment: Thank you i did it.